# Getting text of the element with additional tags inside via selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, text-extraction

I want to get text inside of 'a' tag, but it has 'i' tag with its own text also.
How to filter out 'i' tag text from 'a'? Text inside of 'i' might be different.

[image]

I used `findElement()` with *//div[@class='cart-content-btn']//a/i/following-sibling::node()* but it returns the exception below.

> invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

How to bypass it to get text without 'i' tag text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text content of a parent `a` element and then to reduce the `i` child element text from it, as following:

```java
String entireText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cart-content-btn']//a")).getText().trim();
String iElementText =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cart-content-btn']//a/i")).getText().trim();
String parentTextOnly = entireText.replace(iElementText, "").trim();
```

I've added `.trim()` to remove possible leading or trailing spaces.